# Switching language of streamlit date_input widget

Tags: streamlit

I want to change the language of the months on calendar date_input widget of a streamlit app,  I couldn't find any option who could translate it, anyone have any idea to translate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict with `datetime` months in English as `keys` and months in your language as its `values`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to translate built-in features. You can manipulate the calendar widget by yourself by changing the source code of streamlit, but I would advise against it.